# How to write model file for JAGS binomial using logit function

Tags: r, bayesian, montecarlo, jags

I am working on an assignment using JAGS to model a binomial distribution who's `p` parameter is a function of another variable `d`.

This is what I am trying to do:

1. generate 10000 samples from the posterior for the two parameters alpha/beta
2. produce samples to from the posterior predicted number of success when dist = 25 for 100 attempts
3. calculate 95 credible interval for success rate at 25 feet distance

I have written the model but it is giving an error.

Below is the code I have already tried

```
#R-code
distance=seq(from=2,to=20,by=1)
Ntrys=c(1443,694,455,353,272,256,240,217,200,237,202,192,174,167,201,195,191,147,152)
Nsucc=c(1346,577,337,208,149,136,111,69,67,75,52,46,54,28,27,31,33,20,24)

psucc=Nsucc/Ntrys

glm1.data=list(N=19, Nsucc=Nsucc,psucc=psucc,distance=distance)

glm1.model=jags.model("glm1.model",glm1.data,n.chains=2)

glm1.samps=coda.samples(glm1.model, variable.names=c("alpha", "beta"), 1e5)

#model file
model{ 
    for (i in 1:N){
            Nsucc[i] ~ dbern(psucc[i])
            log((psucc[i])/(1-psucc[i])) <- alpha + beta*(distance[i])
    }
    alpha ~ dunif(-10,10)
    beta ~ dunif(-10,10)
}
```

I get an error

> Error in jags.model("glm1.model", glm1.data, n.chains = 2) :
>     RUNTIME ERROR:
>   Compilation error on line 4.
>   pmiss[1] is a logical node and cannot be observed

I don't think the model file is even setup to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this yes it was the fact that I was passing in precalulated p values that was causing the error, it was overspecified.

Comment: you're welcome .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to calculate the probabilities outside of `rjags` but can use the binomial distribution function, `dbin(p,N)` which takes the arguments, `p`, the probability of success, and `N`, the number of tries. Additionally, the `logit` function can be used as the link function.

The updated model function is then

```
mod <-
"model{ 
    # likelihood
    for (i in 1:N){
            Nsucc[i] ~ dbin(p[i], Ntrys[i])
            logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta*distance[i]
    }
    # priors
    alpha ~ dunif(-10,10)
    beta ~ dunif(-10,10)

}"
```

Predictions can be generated given some value of the predictors by adding the values of the predictors to the data, and appending the relevant number of `NA`'s to the outcome vector. So the data passed to `rjags` becomes

```
glm1.data <- list(N=20, Nsucc=c(Nsucc, NA), Ntrys=c(Ntrys, 100), distance=c(distance, 25))
```

Then compile and run the model

```
# set.seed so sampling is reproducible
library(rjags)
load.module("glm")

glm1.model <- jags.model(textConnection(mod), glm1.data, 
                         n.chains=2,
                         inits=list(.RNG.name="base::Wichmann-Hill",
                                    .RNG.seed=1))
update(glm1.model, n.iter = 1000, progress.bar="none")

# sample: monitor the unknown predictions, Nsucc[20], p[20]
glm1.samps <- coda.samples(glm1.model, variable.names=c("alpha", "beta", "Nsucc[20]", "p[20]"), 1e5)
```

You can then generate intervals from the quantiles

```
s <- summary(glm1.samps)
s$quantiles
```

or the highest density interval

```
library(HDInterval)
hdi(glm1.samps)
```

(just for fun, compare coefficients from `glm`: `summary(glm(cbind(Nsucc, Ntrys-Nsucc) ~ distance, family=binomial))`)