# Can't install package 'Liszt' (not in CRAN) in R 3.6.3

Tags: r, devtools, jags, rtools

I want to install a package that is not found in CRAN.

Below is a downloadlink to the package.
The package makes use of JAGS, of which i have the 64 bit 4.3.0 version of.
`rjags` and `r2jags` packages are installed. Rtools is connected to the pathway. I checked this using

```
Sys.which("make")
## "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

Connection to path was done with `devtools` from this Stacklink:
[How to add Rtools\bin to the system path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539125/how-to-add-rtools-bin-to-the-system-path-in-r)

I use the following code to install the downloaded .tar.gz package:

```
install.packages("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/Liszt_0.8-5_1.tar.gz", repos=NULL,
                 type="source")
```

The package won't installl, instead i get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'Liszt' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'Liszt'
    finding HTML links ... done
    A3ModelFun                              html  
    A5ModelFun                              html  
    Caterpillar                             html  
    LL                                      html  
    Liszt-package                           html  
    extract                                 html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rjags':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS version 4

The rjags package is just an interface to the JAGS library
Make sure you have installed JAGS-4.x.y.exe (for any x >=0, y>=0) from
http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files

Error : package 'rjags' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/Sneve/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Liszt'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/Liszt_0.8-5_1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am trying for a while no, but no success. Any help is much appreciated.

Website providing the package:
http://www.possinghamlab.org/2016-05-30-04-33-10/list-length-analysis.html

package is available here:
http://www.possinghamlab.org/images/LLA/Liszt_0.8-5_1.tar.gz

Comment: Does rjags load okay -- can you run examples using it?

Comment: I cannot run examples since i am not familiar with BUGS language. I do believe the package is loaded correctly. 

{Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.3.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs.}

It does not give any errors when loading the package and also seems to specify the JAGS path correctly.

Comment: given the onload messages it does seem that rjags should work. Try running the example rjags from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55843636/how-to-write-model-file-for-jags-binomial-using-logit-function/55849532#55849532) to test - ( only need to copy and paste code from answer and grab data from the question)

Comment: ... but the package from the link has just a few R functions and doesnt require compilation i.e. you could just copy and paste them into your R session. So oyu could try that. (ps the package in your question installed fine for me)

Comment: hmm is your pc 32 or 64 bit? The messages mention both `*** arch - i386` and `*** arch - x64`

Comment: I used your rjags example to test if the package was working correctly; everything works fine. My computer runs on a 64 bit operating system. I will try to copy the functions from the package. Strange that it does install fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the 64 Bit version of JAGS. Appearently, the package needs both the 32 and the 64 bit version installed on the PC to be able to work. After i installed also the 32 bit version of JAGS, package installed with no problem.

Comment: well done for finding an answer. It does seem weird -- ive never had this problem with rjags. It does remind me of struggles with rjava which ran fine on 64bit Windows but when I tried to install a custom package using rjava i got a lot of errors re 32 bit. I succeeded by reinstalling R but NOT installing  32 bit R when given the installer option. Now I always omit installing 32bit R when on windows.